# Vuetify DataTable Text and PlaceHolders overlap eachother

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify datatable and I fill the table with API- GET Request via Axios.
The problem is when I click Edit Button on the right the placeholder of the textboxes overlap with the selected rows' values.

The issue can be easily understandable from the picture. [image: Problem 1]

Also, when I delete the default headers i.e., (Carbs (g) and Protein (g)) from the code, the actions column is disappearing.. (Picture 2)

[image: Problem 2]

Finally, here is the City.vue

```
    <template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="cities"
    sort-by="Id"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar
        flat
      >
        <v-toolbar-title>CITY CRUD</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider
          class="mx-4"
          inset
          vertical
        ></v-divider>


        <v-spacer></v-spacer>


        <v-dialog
          v-model="dialog"
          max-width="500px"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              color="primary"
              dark
              class="mb-2"
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
              New City
            </v-btn>
          </template>

          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col
                    cols="12"
                    sm="6"
                    md="4"
                  >
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="editedItem.Id"
                      label="Id"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                    cols="12"
                    sm="6"
                    md="4"
                  >
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="editedItem.Text"
                      label="Text"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col
                    cols="12"
                    sm="6"
                    md="4"
                  >
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="editedItem.Description"
                      label="Description"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                 
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn
                color="blue darken-1"
                text
                @click="close"
              >
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                color="blue darken-1"
                text
                @click="save"
              >
                Save
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>


        </v-dialog>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="text-h5">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeDelete">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="deleteItemConfirm">OK</v-btn>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
  <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-btn
        color="primary"
        @click="initialize"
      >
        Reset
      </v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      dialogDelete: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Id',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'Id',
        },
        { text: 'Text', value: 'Text' },
        { text: 'Description', value: 'Description' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
      ],
      cities: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        Id: 0,
        Text: '',
        Description: '',
        
      },
      defaultItem: {
        Id: 0,
        Text: '',
        Description: '',
        
      },
    }),

   

    watch: {
      dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
      },
      dialogDelete (val) {
        val || this.closeDelete()
      },
    },

    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },

    methods: {
      initialize () {
        axios.get("https://localhost:44377/city")
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.cities=response.data;
                });           

      },

      editItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.cities.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialog = true
      },

      deleteItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.cities.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialogDelete = true
      },

      deleteItemConfirm () {
        this.cities.splice(this.editedIndex, 1)
        this.closeDelete()
      },

      close () {
        this.dialog = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        })
      },

      closeDelete () {
        this.dialogDelete = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        })
      },

      save () {
        if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
          Object.assign(this.cities[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
        } else {
          this.cities.push(this.editedItem)
        }
        this.close()
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I was mistakenly deleting the Actions columns as well. Hence, problem 2 has been solved.

Comment: Could you try moving the dialogs outside the data table? If nothing changes, please make a codepen, so we can see the issue replicated.

Comment: Can you try wrapping `this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)` inside `editItem()` in [this.$nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)?